# Looking for a very simple image viewer for usage of viewing graphic design previews

Tags: software-recommendation, graphics, image-editing

Ive been looking for a program, that I can use to preview design outputs. On windows Photofiltre used to do it all very fast, but sadly it is for windows only.

So Im looking for very simple (fast) UI, that really only needs following features:

- Eyedropper / Color picker
- Dimensions tool for measuring (in pixels)
- Button to easily go to 1:1 (actual size of the image)
- (optional) Explorer / Image map (so you can navigate inside picture when zoomed in)

Photoshop has all that, but is more focused on editing images not viewing. I only need something very lightweight to view images. Sadly, to date I have not found such thing for macOS.

Comment: Adobe Bridge, perhaps?

Comment: @Allan Looking something more lightweight and if possible outside of Adobe family.